# The word "still" as an adjective -- does it have a connotation of 'somehow related to death or the dead"?

Tags: meaning, writing-style

I realize that the definition of "still" (used as an adjective) goes like this:

someone or something that is quiet, calm or not moving.

examples:

- the still water of the lake
- still wines (vs. sparkling wines)
- The crowd cheered and then grew still.
- be still, my beating heart!

---

My question is, do native speakers ever pick up an extra shade of meaning: something still "being motionless to the extent of being dead"?

I ask this because the following words exist in the language:

- still life (a painting, drawing of fruit, etc)
- a stillborn child (one who was born dead).

Thanks for answering!

Comment: All those examples mean not moving. However, in stillborn and still life, the extra meaning is dead. Compare still life to the French: une nature morte (dead  nature) and for a child that is born dead: un enfant mort né (a child born dead). .

Comment: It's funny you should use these examples: in French Still life=nature morte (Dead nature) and stillborn=mort-né (born dead)

Comment: Many 'st..' words mean to stand firm: stile, stick, stake, stay, stone ... or to transition to/from stillness: start, stray, stop, staunch ... or to use a straight, firm or tense object: stab, stripe, strap, string ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the following saying suggests what you are referring to, but  generally   I'd say that "still"  just suggest being  *immobile*:

***[Still as death](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/still+as+death)***:

> - (Cliché) immobile; completely still. 
>     (The reference to death gives this expression ominous connotations. *Also: as ~.)
>
>   - *George sat as still as death all afternoon. When the storm was over, everything was suddenly still as death.*

(McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, certainly. The roots are archaic, going back to the distinction of animate vs. inanimate or the quick vs. the dead.

"Still" *denotes* motionless, but has, at the very least, poetic ties to death. 
I would *not* go so far as to say it has *connotations* of death without some sort of context indication like a reference to breath or body, or the addition of some magnifying modifiers.

"She was completely still." certainly brings death to my native-speaking mind, even though it's uncertain. "His chest stilled." or "The engine stilled." are likely evocative of death, too.